# Linux - case command

Tags: bash, scripting, case

How to have spaces or tabs in the menu list?

```
    PS3='Please enter your choice: '
    options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Quit")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
      case $opt in
         "Option 1")
            echo "Your choise is 1"
            ;;
         "Option 2")
            echo "Your choise is 2"
            ;;
         "Quit")
            break
            ;;
         *) echo "Invalid option;;
      esac
    done
```

And I got this:

```
[user@Server:/home/user] ./test.sh
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Quit
Please enter your choice:
```

But I'd like something like this:

```
[user@Server:/home/user] ./test.sh
   1) Option 1
   2) Option 2
   3) Option 3
   4) Quit
Please enter your choice:
```

Ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `case` statement. It's the `select` that displays the menu. As an aside note: If you use `case $REPLY in`, you can test on the _numbers_ instead. That way you don't have to repeat all those strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` statement in `bash`, which is what displays the menu, does not allow specifying an indent for the menu.

---

Just a comment on the code:  It's usually easier to let the `case` statement act on `$REPLY` rather than the variable with the selected string.  It saves you from having to type in the strings twice.

E.g.

```
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
  case $REPLY in
     1)
        echo "Your choice is 1"
        ;;
     2)
        echo "Your choice is 2"
        ;;
     3)
        break
        ;;
     *) echo 'Invalid option' >&2
  esac
done
```

or, for this specific example,

```
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
  case $REPLY in
     [1-2])
        printf 'Your choice is %s\n' "$REPLY"
        ;;
     3)
        break
        ;;
     *) echo 'Invalid option' >&2
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not too hard to (roughly) reimplement `select` manually and fine-tune the display, at least as long as you don't have so many options to need a multi-column listing.

```
#!/bin/bash

# print the prompt from $1, and a menu of the other arguments
choose() {
    local prompt=$1
    shift
    local i=0
    for opt in "$@"; do
        # we have to do the numbering manually...
        printf "  %2d) %s\n" "$((i += 1))" "$opt"
    done
    read -p "$prompt: "
}

options=("Foo" "Bar" "Quit")
while choose 'Please enter your choice'  "${options[@]}"; do
    case $REPLY in
    1) echo "you chose 'foo'" ;;
    2) echo "you chose 'bar'";;
    3) echo 'you chose to quit'; break;;
    *) echo 'invalid choice';;
    esac
done
```

Of course, this could be extended to take the array keys (indices) into account, and to present them as the choices in the menu, instead of a running counter.